# Arraylist within Arraylist not working

Tags: java, arraylist

```
List<List<String>> titleID = null;
        List<String> child = null;

        String name = "";
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ArraylistClass.indexAllEntrySearch.size(); i++) {

            if (child == null) {
                child = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
            if (titleID == null) {
                titleID = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
            }
            if (!ArraylistClass.indexAllEntrySearch.get(i)
                    .startsWith("   ")) {

                name = ArraylistClass.indexAllEntrySearch.get(i).toString();

                if (!child.isEmpty()) {

                    titleID.add(j, child);
                    j++;
                    Log.v("startsWith ", child.toString());
                    Log.v(" !! startsWith ", titleID.toString());
                    child.clear();
                    child = null;
                }

            } else {
                child.add(ArraylistClass.indexAllEntrySearch.get(i)
                        .toString());

            }

        }
        Log.v(" !! startsWith ", titleID.toString());
```

it shows result..

> 01-06 10:58:44.726: V/!! startsWith(7079): [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [   Pain Assessment,    Heart Failure,    Heart Failure,    Alternative Strong Opioids,    Analgesic Prescribing,    Opioid side effects & toxicity,    Pain Assessment,    Heart Failure,    Breakthrough pain,    Analgesic Prescribing,    Heart Failure]]

previous item becomes empty..why...?

//*************************//

My Arraylist is

public static ArrayList indexAllEntrySearch = new ArrayList();
and items are

[5 HT-3 antagonists,    Nausea & Vomiting, Acetaminophen. See Paracetamol, Acetylcholinesterase inhibitors,    Delirium & Confusion, Action plan,    Referral to Hospital, Acupuncture,    Nausea & Vomiting,    Pruritus (Itching),    Sweats & Hot Flushes,    Multiple Sclerosis,    Other Pain Interventions,    Pruritus (Itching), Acute inflammatory episode (AIE),    Lymphoedema, Adcortyl in Orabase,    Oral problems (Overview), Adjuvant analgesics,    Neuropathic pain,    Analgesic Prescribing, Admission to hospital,    Referral to Hospital, Adrenaline,    Bleeding & haemorrhage, Advance Decisions,    Resuscitation Guidelines (DNAR's),    Advance care planning,    Parkinson's disease, Advance Directives,    Mental Capacity,    Advance care planning, Age,    Co-morbidity & Frailty in the Elderly, Agitation,    Delirium & Confusion,    Terminal Phase,    Quick Guide - Agitation, AIDS,    Anorexia, Cachexia & Asthenia,    Certification of Death & Referral to the Coroner,    Useful Contacts,    HIV & AIDS, Akathisia,    Delirium & Confusion, Albumin infusions,    Ascites, Aldosterone antagonists,    Ascites, Alfentanil,    Syringe Drivers - Commonly used drugs,    Opioid Potency Ratios,    Prescribing in Renal disease,    Dose adjustment of drugs in renal disease,    Analgesia in Liver Disease,    Parenteral alternatives to morphine,    Controlled Drug formulations,    Drugs A-D,    Syringe Drivers - Commonly used drugs,    Dose adjustment of drugs in renal disease,    Analgesia in Liver Disease,    Parenteral alternatives to morphine,    Prescribing in Renal disease,    Drugs A-D,    Controlled Drug formulations, Algorithm,    Completing the LCP, Alternative. See Complementary therapies, Alzheimer's disease,    Delirium & Confusion,    Tissue Donation, Amantadine,    Parkinson's disease,    Multiple Sclerosis, Amiodarone,    Anticoagulation, Amitriptyline,    Nausea & Vomiting,    Neuropathic pain,    Depression,    Delirium & Confusion,    Fitness to Drive,    Multiple Sclerosis,    Heart Failure,    Dose adjustment of drugs in renal disease,    Analgesia in Liver Disease,    Drugs A-D,    Delirium & Confusion,    Heart Failure,    Analgesia in Liver Disease,    Neuropathic pain,    Depression,    Drugs A-D, Amoxicillin,    Antibiotics, Anaemia,    Dyspnoea,    Pruritus (Itching),    Lymphoedema,    Quick Guide - Breathlessness, Anaerobic infection,    Oral problems (Overview), Anaesthetic procedures,    Other Pain Interventions, Analgesic ladder,    Analgesic Prescribing,    Delirium & Confusion, Analgesics,    Pain Assessment,    Heart Failure,    Heart Failure,    Alternative Strong Opioids,    Analgesic Prescribing,    Opioid side effects & toxicity,    Pain Assessment,    Heart Failure,    Breakthrough pain,    Analgesic Prescribing,    Heart Failure, Angular cheilitis,    Oral problems (Overview)]

**this contain Parent(name)  and child(name )**
e.g 
5 HT-3 antagonists,    Nausea & Vomiting, Acetaminophen. See Paracetamol

Parent is **5 HT-3 antagonists** and its child name is **Nausea & Vomiting, Acetaminophen. See Paracetamol**

Header: 5 HT-3 antagonists
  Child:    Nausea & Vomiting
  Header: Acetaminophen. See Paracetamol
  Header: Acetylcholinesterase inhibitors
  Child:    Delirium & Confusion
  Header: Action plan
  Child:    Referral to Hospital
  Header: Acupuncture
  Child:    Nausea & Vomiting
  Child:    Pruritus (Itching)
  Child:    Sweats & Hot Flushes
  Child:    Multiple Sclerosis
  Child:    Other Pain Interventions
  Child:    Pruritus (Itching)
  Header: Acute inflammatory episode (AIE)
  Child:    Lymphoedema
  Header: Adcortyl in Orabase
  Child:    Oral problems (Overview)
  Header: Adjuvant analgesics
  Child:    Neuropathic pain
  Child:    Analgesic Prescribing
  Header: Admission to hospital
  Child:    Referral to Hospital
  Header: Adrenaline
  Child:    Bleeding & haemorrhage
  Header: Advance Decisions
  Child:    Resuscitation Guidelines (DNAR's)
  Child:    Advance care planning
  Child:    Parkinson's disease
  Header: Advance Directives
  Child:    Mental Capacity
  Child:    Advance care planning
  Header: Age
  Child:    Co-morbidity & Frailty in the Elderly

```
   parent name start without space and child name start with space name inside the array..
```

i want create expandable listview how can i manage data....

Comment: What's `ArraylistClass`?

Comment: What is the expected output and what are the inputs?  Please be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the problem:

```
titleID.add(j, child);
j++;
Log.v("startsWith ", child.toString());
Log.v(" !! startsWith ", titleID.toString());
child.clear();
child = null;
```

You should remove `child.clear()`, since that would clear the list you just added to `titleID`. Instead, just clear the reference as you already do (`child = null`), so that a new `child` instance will be created on the next iteration.